# How to do a "try_lock" with an "upgrade_to_unique_lock"

Tags: c++, boost, locks

I want to perform an upgrade_to_unique_lock on an upgrade_lock without blocking but a cursory look at the Boost source code (v1.46.1) shows that this is impossible?  Is my approach wrong?

I want to first obtain a read lock on a resource that can also potentially be held for reading by other threads.  Then I want to see if it is available for writing and if not (other shared read locks are currently held on it) simply do it later.

```
// No way to specify the boost::try_to_lock object
explicit upgrade_to_unique_lock(upgrade_lock<Mutex>& m_):
    source(&m_),exclusive(move(*source))
```

I'm trying to procedurally generate terrain tiles (pages) seamlessly using the midpoint displacement algorithm asynchronously.  This requires seeding the subject terrain tile (center) with edges obtained from the 4 surrounding tiles (north, west, east, south).  Edges are collected only from neighbors that exist and are fully generated already.  The implementation should block on one neighbor tile at a time and not hold read locks of other neighbors freeing them-up to be generated at any time.  When a tile is being generated, it must guarantee that no other threads have write locks to its neighbors, read locks are ok.  Also, there should not be a daisy-chain of threads waiting on write-locks needlessly (i.e. tiles two tiles apart in distance should be able to generate independently of each other).

My implementation depends on a third-party algorithm that requests pages asynchronously as needed based on viewing distance from a camera.  It looks like it can arbitrarily make up to 16 asynchronous requests for pages / tiles in no particular order.

Comment: `Then I want to see if it is available for writing and if not (other shared read locks are currently held on it) simply do it later.` <-- You can't do that using a lock. What's stopping two threads from attempting to do the write at the same time? I don't believe most systems allow you to do that kind of "attempted lock".

Comment: See: http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/bloomington/shared_mutex.html I am the inventor of the `upgrade_mutex`.  The spec got mangled in the boost implementation.  The link I've provided provides a spec which does what you want.  I am trying to get this spec into the next C++ standard (perhaps into a technical report first).  If this spec looks good to you, make noise about it.  Let your national body representative know that this is what you want.  Let this crowd know that it is what you want.  Let the crowd at comp.std.c++ know.  If it is not what you want, let me know.

Comment: What are you doing with this resource? It seems strange to want to try to do something, and if you can't do something else. Do you ever get back to retrying? Maybe if you got a slightly more concrete we could suggest a better method.

Comment: @Howard: I'm actually really surprised that isn't in the standard already, I assumed it already was. :o

Comment: This is probably where I could use some insight.  I am trying to make 4 read locks (north, east, south, west) and upgrade 1 read to write lock (center) all atomically.  So basically I want to do 5 try locks inside one master lock and if any of them fail then all locks are released followed by the master lock.  There shall only be two states: obtain 4 read locks and 1 upgraded write lock or none at all.  It's too complicated and I don't like it, but I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: @Jonny: But what are all these locks *for*? What work is being done, what's the computation?

Comment: @Jonny: (Describing my proposal, not boost)  If you try-upgrade from shared to upgrade, at least one of your locks will make it to upgrade.  You can then block that upgrade lock on exclusive access and be assured it will get it - atomically.  The two examples in the proposal take this path (one with a try-timed from shared to upgrade, and one with a try from shared to upgrade).  My understanding is that you can't do this with boost.  The boost author believe such transformations to be too dangerous to offer.

Comment: @GMan:  This was proposed for C++0x.  But as described in my proposal, in 2007 we agreed on the "Kona Compromise" whereby we limited the scope of C++0x by purposefully cutting "read/write" mutexes so that we could ship by 2009. :-\  It was a good idea at the time.  I wish it would've worked.

Comment: @Howard: Yes that spec particularly contains features I think I need, particularly atomic locking of multiple locks (std::lock, already in the C++ standard?) and condition_variable_any that does not hold a shared lock while waiting for a resource to be ready for processing.  Also want to be able to acquire a shared lock on a resource (to query its state) before aggressively obtaining an exclusive upgraded write lock on it.  Acquisition of an exclusive lock may not be necessary depending on the resource's state.

Comment: C++11 has `std::lock` and `std::condition_variable_any` (and so does boost).  C++11 lacks `shared_lock`, though if you write one yourself, it will work with `std::condition_variable_any`.  Boost has `shared_lock`, but its syntax and semantics differ vastly with respect to my proposal as far as conversion (and try-conversion) among shared and exclusive goes.

Comment: std::lock would help reduce my LOC by 36.  What's the import header for this feature?  My MSVC++ doesn't seem to recognize it.

Comment: `std::lock` lives in `<mutex>`.  Boost has this feature if you can't get it from MSVC++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straw man answer.  I'm pretty sure this isn't a valid answer.  But I can't put it in a comment because of formatting concerns.

To generate the center tile I would be tempted to do something like this:

```
tile::generate_center()
{
    tile& north = ...;
    tile& east = ...;
    tile& south = ...;
    tile& west = ...;
    std::unique_lock<mutex_type> l0(mutex(), std::defer_lock);
    shared_lock<mutex_type> ln(north.mutex(), std::defer_lock);
    shared_lock<mutex_type> le(east.mutex(), std::defer_lock);
    shared_lock<mutex_type> ls(south.mutex(), std::defer_lock);
    shared_lock<mutex_type> lw(west.mutex(), std::defer_lock);
    std::lock(l0, ln, le, ls, lw);
    // This is exclusively locked, neighbors are share locked
    // ...
}
```

This is using C++11 bits like `std::unique_lock` and `std::defer_lock`.  I believe you can get this functionality from boost too (not positive though).

This routine atomically exclusively locks the center, and share-locks the neighbors.  It blocks until it can get all of the locks.  It doesn't prevent its neighbors from doing the same thing.  That is, use of `std::lock` will ensure there is no deadlock.

I'm very much unsure that this is actually addressing what you're trying to do.  But perhaps it will help lead to an answer...

Comment: This is essentially what I ended-up with except I didn't use std::lock because I don't think I have that feature.  The approach works, having trouble breaking it or deadlocking it.

Comment: Try `boost::lock` if you don't have `std::lock`.  This code will deadlock without it if two adjacent tiles try to simultaneously generate.